# Command binding on window exit by pressing "X"

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application that uses MVVM.
I need to bind the window exit("X") to my cancel command that is in my viewModel.
I have a cancel button on my form that uses the same command for closing the window.
After clicking on "X" my closing event is called twice (first closing from the event trigger(XAML) and then from cancel command) and the application throws an exception.

Here is some code:

```
public ICommand CancelCommand {
        get {
            return _cancel ?? (_cancel = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                bool result = false;
                if (_protocolSettingsModel.IsDirty || _overridesModel.IsDirty || _mappingsModel.IsDirty || _csvMappingsModel.IsDirty || _generalModel.IsDirty)
                {
                    result = MessageBoxTemplates.Changes();
                    if (result)
                    {
                        OnClosingRequest();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    OnClosingRequest();
                }
            }));
        }

        set {
            _cancel = value;
        }
    }
```

Thats the command. Now the window.cs code:

```
public SimulationWindow(ManageSimulationViewModel vm) {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = (_simulationModel = vm);
        _simulationModel.ClosingRequest += (sender, e) => Close();
    }
```

And the XAML :

```html
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Your events could be hooked up incorrectly. Post code of your events and their handlers so people can take a look - its hard to diagnose things blind

Comment: how are you hooking up the command? simply via a button, or through an event. as Takarii has said, we could use some code samples to better assist you

Comment: It's near impossible to tell you what you've done wrongly without knowing exactly what you've done in the first place. Provide a [mcve].